# Why it takes so long for a popup to be displayed when clicked using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

**I think the mystery is solved. I find that it is very slow only when the Chrome window is minimized.**

When I manually click the caret, the popup is displayed instantly. But when I click it using Selenium, it takes more than five seconds.

[image]

My code is as follows. Is there anything that can be optimized? Thank you!

```
subratings_trigger = review.find_element_by_class_name("review-details__review-details-module__ratingCaret")

s_time = time.time()
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(subratings_trigger).perform()
print("time to pop up", time.time() - s_time)
```

Comment: I think the mystery is solved. I find that it is very slow only when the Chrome window is minimized.

Comment: You can maximize the window in selenium using `driver.maximize_window()` or `options.add_argument("--start-maximized")`. does that solve it?

Comment: This happens when I manually minimize the Chrome window so that it won't get in the way. It doesn't happen even when the Chome window is covered by another screen. So, it is fine now.

Comment: Have you tried to make it headless then?

Comment: No, I didn't try. I always want to see what's going on on the screen.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I just tried. In the headless mode, there is no issue. However, an additional issue arises. There is one element that can't be extracted in the headless mode. That may be resolved by tweaking the code.

Comment: You can use [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) if there is a delay in extracting an element.